# Java Performance runtime generics

Tags: java, performance

I was wondering when you are implementing a method that returns a type, if there is any significant runtime performance difference between implementing a method that returns a hardcoded getKind versus a Class.class that is passed in during instantiation.

1. Hardcoded performance:

   ```
    public static class HardcodedFoo {

        public Class<Integer> getKind() {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    }
   ```

versus

2. Version where type is passed in the constructor.

   ```
   public static class Foo<E> {

      private final Class<E> kind;

      public Foo(final Class<E> kind) {this.kind = kind;}

      public Class<E> getKind() {
         return kind;
      }
   }
   ```

I know there will be some performance hits in instantiation because we need to pass in a field as well as Foo needing to take up more memory, but I highly doubt there is any significant runtime performance (the run time performance is just looking up a value in memory, which is something that happens all the time, one more lookup in memory wouldn't hurt since we aren't building precision rockets running on cellphones or anything).  At least using milliseconds precision I can hardly detect any real difference.

Would there be any difference at all to really justify the first hardcoded approach? Considering the hardcoded approach would lead to designs that would involve a lot of duplication whereas the second approach I can simplify to a single class.

In fact, I would argue that the memory that is actually used and performance hit is not as impactful as the actual memory that is used to load up all the duplicate classes into the JVM's permgen space (or metaspace) or whatever.

Comment: As a short answer, not really. The best way to evaluate the performance hit would be looking at the bytecode or timing a large number of instantiations in a loop — but it's unlikely to ever be a bottleneck in a real application or algorithm.

Comment: I think you're right in the last paragraph (Although I am not 100% sure). A simple getter, and the space it takes to store a reference, is probably a much less expensive approach for simulating reified generics than an approach which loads separate classes for each variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At least using milliseconds precision I can hardly detect any real difference.

You will need nano-second precision or better. i.e 0.000001 milli-second

The main difference is as you have noted is the additional field.  This might make a difference to the size but as objects are typically 8 byte aligned and references are typically 4 bytes, the reference might consume padding and add nothing the object size.

The memory access involved might add some time but since the header will have been accessed by this point, access to an additional field in likely to be in the L1 cache.  i.e. it would typically add ~1 ns.